# Git Error fatal: Could not set SSL backend to 'openssl': already set

Tags: git

I have been facing an error (fatal: Could not set SSL backend to 'openssl': already set) when I am trying to push my changes from local to remote git repository and cannot push any changes. If anyone knows about this error and how can we resolve it or how can can we reset the http.sslbackend to default please help.

Answer (score 3):

You must uninstall the git, clean the temporary files with any cleaner, and reinstall the git with the latest version.
https://git-scm.com/download/

Comment: was running 2.20.  `sudo apt-get remove --purge git`   then removed .gitconfig from ~.   Then installed git again.  That did it.    btw I use this ppa for git https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: I had this issue using Git in WSL (with Ubuntu). `sudo apt-get remove --purge git && rm ~/.git config` then reinstalling fixed it for me thanks @DKebler

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because i custom compiled git `--with-openssl` but had my `~/.gitconfig` configured with:

```
[http]
    sslbackend = openssl
[https]
    sslbackend = openssl
```

Seems that `git` doesn't like you to specify if it was pre-compiled that way. In any case, removing those global configs worked.

Answer (score 1):

Even after reinstalling git issue can be still persist, Then try this command. `git config --global --unset http.sslBackend`